# send whole batch to dlt without retrying

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

i'm using spring kafka and i have a kafka consumer written in java spring boot. My consumer consume batch wise and relevant configuration beans are given below.

```
@Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
 
    // default configs like bootstrap servers, key and value deserializers are here

    config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "5");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
  }


  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.DEBUG);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    return factory;
  }
```

I consume messages and send those messages to an API endpoint. If the api is not available or if the rest template throw an error i want to send the whole batch to a DLT without retrying.
What i want to do is send the whole batch to the DLT without retrying. If we throw `BatchListenerFailedException`  that specific index number owning message from the batch will send to a DLT. In `BatchListenerFailedException` we can pass only one integer value as index value and not a list. But what i want is to send the whole batch as it is to a DLT topic without retrying. Is there a way to achieve that?

my spring Kafka version is 2.8.6

**Edit**

my default error handler is like below

```
@Bean
  public CommonErrorHandler commonErrorHandler() {

    ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries exponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries = new ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries(5);
    exponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries.setInitialInterval(my val);
    exponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries.setMultiplier(my val);
    exponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries.setMaxInterval(my val);

    DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(
            new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate(),
                    (record, exception) -> new TopicPartition(record.topic() + "-dlt", record.partition())),
            exponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries);
    errorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(ParseException.class);
    errorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(EventHubNonRetryableException.class);
    return errorHandler;
  }
```

In my case in used `ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries` instead of FixedBackOff. In my case i have 3 scenarios.

1 - Retry messages and send it to DLT (Throwing any other exception than `BatchListenerFailedException`)

2 - Send couple of messages from the batch to DLT without retrying (Using `BatchListenerFailedException` for this)

3 - Send whole batch to the DLT without retrying.

3rd one is the place where i'm struggling. If i send some other exception then it will retry couple of times. (Even if i used `FixedBackOff` instead of `ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw something else other than `BatchListenerFailedException`; use a `DefaultErrorHandler` with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` with no retries (`new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L)`).

**EDIT**

Starting with versions 3.0.0, 2.9.3, 2.8.11, you can configure not retryable exceptions for batch errors.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2459

See

```java
/**
 * Add exception types to the default list. By default, the following exceptions will
 * not be retried:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link DeserializationException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MessageConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ConversionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link MethodArgumentResolutionException}</li>
 * <li>{@link NoSuchMethodException}</li>
 * <li>{@link ClassCastException}</li>
 * </ul>
 * All others will be retried, unless {@link #defaultFalse()} has been called.
 * @param exceptionTypes the exception types.
 * @see #removeClassification(Class)
 * @see #setClassifications(Map, boolean)
 */
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs")
public final void addNotRetryableExceptions(Class<? extends Exception>... exceptionTypes) {
    add(false, exceptionTypes);
    notRetryable(Arrays.stream(exceptionTypes));
}
```

Note that 2.8.x is now out of OSS support. https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support

Comment: actually i'm using a default error handler like below and for that i'm using ExponentialBackOff. 

`DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(
            new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate(),
                    (record, exception) -> new TopicPartition(record.topic() + "-dlt", record.partition())),
            exponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries);`

If i throw something else other than `BatchListenerFailedException` it will retry 5 times (according to my configuration).

Comment: is there a way to retry it only one time with above default handler?

Comment: Don't put code in comments; edit the question instead and comment that you have done so. `new FixedBackOff(delay, 1L)`.

Comment: i updated the question. Can you please check it ?

Comment: You can configure exceptions that are not retryable - see the edit.